# Which is the best hosting solution for a node.js telegram bot on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, hosting, telegram-bot

I need to host my node.js telegram bot on Azure. I need to have a MySql database too. Is an Ubuntu virtual machine a good option? 
I was thinking of using the B1s virtual machine. Do you have any advice for me? Is there any other Azure service that I could use for my purpose?

I use Azure because I am a student and I have a 100 euro credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save money the best option is to use this VM size, that is not to expensive, and to improve your performance you can choose a premium SSD when creating the VM. I don't now exactly about your application server requirements, if you need more CPU or RAM you can change VM size any time you want.

What is good to save money is to use Azure Automation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/), with this resource you can shutdown your VM in order to stop billing you for the resource. I just will give you one more advice, if you shutdown the VM, be carefull with the VM IP address, by default when creating a VM It comes as dynamic, remember to change this to static.